# Can I use wordpress.com's Upcoming Events Widget in my local wordpress installation?

Tags: php, wordpress, events

I need to show an iCalendar feed in one of my pages. I found "Upcoming Events" Widget & Shortcode in wordpress.com -> http://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/upcoming-events/

How can I use this widget in my local wordpress installation? (Or are there any other plugins that you might know to do that. I have been searching for a while and could not find anything useful.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't use any similar plugins myself but there are hell of a lot premium plugins available on "codecanyon".

http://codecanyon.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=upcoming+events

Here is a one that get events from Google Calendar, iCal (.ics) or XML.

http://codecanyon.net/item/google-ical-xml-event-list-calendar-for-php/2560605?WT.ac=solid_search_item&WT.seg_1=solid_search_item&WT.z_author=RikdeVos